# How to Inject Parameter From URL into HTML using AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express

I am building an application (using express, node, and angular) that stores clients and has the ability to view their info. Each client is assigned an id key. I have created a link such that when the client's name is clicked, it goes to a url that is like so :     `client/{{client.id}}`. I want to extract this parameter, id, so I can filter the clients and show only the one with that id. Here is my express.js, where I find the parameter id and print it in console:

```
// express stuff
app.param('id', function (req, res, next, id) {
console.log(req.params.id);
next();
});
app.get('/client/:id', routes.clientpage);
```

Now, I see the id printed in console log -- but, using Angular, how would I inject this parameter into a filter? This is what I think, but I evidently wrong :

`<ng-repeat="client in clients | orderBy:'id' | filter:{id:{{$req.params.id}}} | limitTo: 1"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it whi some url parsing expression like this:

```
//in controller
$scope.clientId = document.location.href.split('client/')[1];

//in template
<ng-repeat="client in clients | orderBy:'id' | filter:{id:clientId} | limitTo: 1"/>
```

That will work for urls like `myapp.com/example/client/46235`, but may fail for `myapp.com/example/client/46235/getsmth` so you may want to use other solutions:

- [angular UI router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing) for client side app naviagtion
- Output this ID in some part of you server generated template.

Comment: Will you please explain as to how document.location.href.split('client/')[1]; achieves the effect that is desired ?

Comment: document.location.href.split('client/')[1] uses string split function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) - will take the url of the page (say for example full url is 'myapp.com/example/client/46235') and will return you the last part - '46235'. Then you can assign it to some scope variable ($scope.clientId for example) and the use it in the filter expression.

Comment: thank you, I am having an issue with this at the moment. Do you think you would be able to advise?

Comment: can you be more specific, what's the problem?

Comment: Okay, so the routing works fine and when I click on a client I am led to the client page with the specified client's info. I have four buttons that lead to other pages that show different info of the client. When I click on one of these buttons, say case information, it always leads to me the client with id of 2, not the id of the parameter. The link url that I am using is ci/{{client.id}}.

Comment: Also, now in the console log all the parameters show initially as the parameter but then turn into semi-colons. I have not changed any code, but this has started to happen.